# global menu not working on some apps like evince and nautilus

Tags: globalmenu

Global menu does not work on evince, nautilus, etc, how can I get it back to these apps which should be compatible with global menu.

Answer (score 0):

Please see https://bugs.launchpad.net/ayatana-design/+bug/1131664

There are people working on fixes to use classic menus instead of the new simple menus.